# Profile/pause/stacktrace binary in linux after a fork

Tags: c++, linux, profiling

I normally use valgrind to profile my binaries on linux. This binary uses `fork()` and I can't seem to get the profile data. I mostly need to pause at this point which takes several seconds and see the function or stacktrace. How do I do this in ubuntu? (or debian)

Comment: Can you just use gdb?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: It forks which creates a few problems. What command do I use if i know the pid?

Comment: I thought gdb knew about multiple threads. There's another couple tools, pstack and lsstack that maybe you could tell which pid to look at. (I'm Windows - sorry, but I do use gdb when I have to.)